# Why does Windows.Media.Audio.AudioGraph has inferior resampling quality compared to Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer?

Tags: .net, audio, uwp, winui-3, windows-core-audio

I'm working on a modulated signal generator that uses audio render as output.

So far I tested two methods of output from my application to hardware:

- `Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer`
- `Windows.Media.Audio.AudioGraph`

My generated input data encoding is always `AudioEncodingProperties.CreatePcm(44100, 1, 8)`. Byte stream is as follows:

- repeated sequence of `{ 0xfb, 0x05, 0x80 }` bytes when "carrier present"
- repeated sequence of `{ 0x80 }` bytes otherwise

To verify output signal I record it from WASAPI loopback device using Audacity.

When the system shared mode default format is 44100 Hz I have bit-perfect output from both `MediaPlayer` and `AudioGraph` (here and later: the top chart is a whole frame, the bottom chart is zoomed in part of it):

- MediaPlayer and AudioGraph give identical output (Audacity Project Rate is 44100 Hz)

[image: frame]

[image: zoom in]

But when the default format is 48000 Hz looks like the system does resampling. And the quality of this resampling differs so much, that modulated signal receiver accepts the signal output from `MediaPlayer` but not from `AudioGraph`. Here's how those signals look like (not sure if I have to record that signals when Audacity Project Rate selected 44100 Hz or 48000 Hz, so I present both variants here (and after the first comment I added the signals recorded on higher frequencies)):

- MediaPlayer (Audacity Project Rate is 44100 Hz)
  [image: MediaStreamSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_44k1Hz_zoom1]
  [image: MediaStreamSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_44k1Hz_zoom2]
- MediaPlayer (Audacity Project Rate is 48000 Hz)
  [image: MediaStreamSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_48kHz_zoom1]
  [image: MediaStreamSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_48kHz_zoom2]
- MediaPlayer (Audacity Project Rate is 88200 Hz)
  [image: MediaStreamSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_88k2Hz_zoom1]
  [image: MediaStreamSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_88k2Hz_zoom2]
- MediaPlayer (Audacity Project Rate is 96000 Hz)
  [image: MediaStreamSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_96kHz_zoom1]
  [image: MediaStreamSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_96kHz_zoom2]
- MediaPlayer (Audacity Project Rate is 192000 Hz)
  [image: MediaStreamSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_192kHz_zoom1]
  [image: MediaStreamSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_192kHz_zoom2]
- AudioGraph (Audacity Project Rate is 44100 Hz)
  [image: AudioGraphSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_44k1Hz_zoom1]
  [image: AudioGraphSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_44k1Hz_zoom2]
- AudioGraph (Audacity Project Rate is 48000 Hz)
  [image: AudioGraphSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_48kHz_zoom1]
  [image: AudioGraphSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_48kHz_zoom2]
- AudioGraph (Audacity Project Rate is 88200 Hz)
  [image: AudioGraphSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_88k2Hz_zoom1]
  [image: AudioGraphSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_88k2Hz_zoom2]
- AudioGraph (Audacity Project Rate is 96000 Hz)
  [image: AudioGraphSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_96kHz_zoom1]
  [image: AudioGraphSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_96kHz_zoom2]
- AudioGraph (Audacity Project Rate is 192000 Hz)
  [image: AudioGraphSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_192kHz_zoom1]
  [image: AudioGraphSignalOutput_44k1Hz_48kHz_192kHz_zoom2]

Difference is huge enough, so `MediaPlayer` output signal works for the receiver even when system output set to 48 kHz, while `AudioGraph` in the same circumstances doesn't.

My primary question is: *Why*?

And, if it's possible to somehow correct `AudioGraph`'s output, then *How*?

Here are some important code snippets for context (the code is the same for all the above-recorded signals):

- `MediaPlayer` init:

```
        var encProps = AudioEncodingProperties.CreatePcm(44100, 1, 8);
        var streamDesc = new AudioStreamDescriptor(encProps);
        var streamSource = new MediaStreamSource(streamDesc);
        streamSource.Starting += StreamSource_Starting;
        streamSource.SampleRequested += StreamSource_SampleRequested;
        streamSource.Closed += StreamSource_Closed;
        //streamSource.IsLive = true; // No effect?
        streamSource.BufferTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
        
        // if don't want to customize SMTC (System Media Transport Controls)
        //mediaPlayer.SetMediaSource(streamSource);

        // if want to customize SMTC (System Media Transport Controls)
        var mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromMediaStreamSource(streamSource);
        var playbackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(mediaSource);
        var mediaItemDisplayProperties = playbackItem.GetDisplayProperties();
        mediaItemDisplayProperties.Type = Windows.Media.MediaPlaybackType.Music;
        mediaItemDisplayProperties.MusicProperties.Title = "LG Flatron Mx94D-PZ IR Control";
        mediaItemDisplayProperties.MusicProperties.Artist = "Media Stream Signal Output";
        playbackItem.ApplyDisplayProperties(mediaItemDisplayProperties);
        mediaPlayer.Source = playbackItem;
        
        mediaPlayer.RealTimePlayback = true;
```

- `AudioGraph` init:

```
        var audioGraphSettings = new AudioGraphSettings(Windows.Media.Render.AudioRenderCategory.Media);
        audioGraphSettings.EncodingProperties =
            AudioEncodingProperties.CreatePcm(44100, 1, 8);
        var audioGraphCreationResult = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(audioGraphSettings);
        if (audioGraphCreationResult.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
        {
            throw audioGraphCreationResult.ExtendedError;
        }

        audioGraph = audioGraphCreationResult.Graph;

        var deviceOutputNodeCreationResult = await audioGraph.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();
        if (deviceOutputNodeCreationResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
        {
            throw deviceOutputNodeCreationResult.ExtendedError;
        }

        audioDeviceOutputNode = deviceOutputNodeCreationResult.DeviceOutputNode;

        var encProps = AudioEncodingProperties.CreatePcm(CarrierSampleSet.SampleRate, 1, 8);
        audioFrameInputNode = audioGraph.CreateFrameInputNode(encProps);
        audioFrameInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(audioDeviceOutputNode);
        audioFrameInputNode.Stop(); // Initialize the Frame Input Node in the stopped state
        audioFrameInputNode.QuantumStarted += AudioFrameInputNode_QuantumStarted;
        audioFrameInputNode.AudioFrameCompleted += AudioFrameInputNode_AudioFrameCompleted;
```

I tried to influence `AudioGraph`'s output.

In the `AudioGraph` init I:

- tried setting encoding properties for the whole `AudioGraph` object (so all the children nodes have the same `Pcm(44100, 1, 8)` encoding),
- tried setting `Pcm(44100, 1, 8)` encoding for `audioFrameInputNode` only, so the rest of `AudioGraph` nodes get encoding with the system default sample rate.

Looks like `audioDeviceOutputNode` ignores its `EncodingProperties.SampleRate` and just obeys the system default setting. The results are the same. Well, not just the same... *identical*!

Comment: The signal looks significantly corrupted in all cases.  An essential detail is missing from the question, the frequency of the signals.  "IR Control" is a cue, a typical carrier frequency is 38KHz.  Which makes Audacity the wrong tool to sample the signals, it can't sample fast enough to stay clear of the [Shannon-Nyquestion sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem).  The result is aliasing, which adds random frequencies to the original signal, thus corrupting it.  44.1KHz was picked to sample audio, 20KHz max.

Comment: I provided all the frequencies: "My generated input data encoding is always AudioEncodingProperties.CreatePcm(44100, 1, 8)". You're right about IR control carrier frequency being 38 kHz. The nearest sound sampling frequency is 44.1 kHz, so I use that as carrier. And it works.

Comment: To clarify regarding frequencies: Input is always 44.1 kHz 8-bit PCM. When system default frequency is 44.1 kHz signal is bit-perfect (shown it sampled at 44.1 kHz in Audacity). When system default frequency is 48 kHz I get distorted signals (shown them sampled at 44.1 kHz and 48 kHz, will add at higher frequency)

Comment: I've got response from the team about this. It says that `Different audio pipelines can potentially add in various effect APOs (LFX / GFX) as part of the playback pipeline.   Some of these are included and enabled by the audio driver.  Try disabling all effect filters and see if that makes a difference as part of resampling`. Could you please try to resample it again after disabling all effect filters?

Comment: Hello, Roy. Nice to see you here too.

Sorry for the late response.

> "Try disabling all effect filters and see if that makes a difference as part of resampling"

Do you mean "Disable all enhancements" in the `mmsys.cpl`'s Enhancements tab?

I just rechecked that: the results are the same. `Windows.Media.Audio.AudioGraph` gives badly resampled audio while `Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer` and `System.Media.SoundPlayer` give much better output (moreover, the latter two provide identical output).